# How to get the average time of a call within a date range

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a table, tblCandidates, with field PacerCallDuration_1 of type Date/Time.  I would like to find the average time of the calls between today and today - DateRng.  DateRng is an integer of how many days I want to go backwards in data, e.g. 30.

```
Dim PCD1 As Date
Dim DateRng as integer
Dim AvgCallTime As Date
AvgCallTime  = DoCmd.RunSQL "select cdate(AVG([PacerCallDuration_1]))_
 from tblCandidates"
```

It does not like my SQL statement and and other items in that line I have tried.
Searching the site I find "How can I get the average of a date field?" was close but not close enough.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *DAvg*:

```
DateRng = 5    ' for example.
AvgCallTime = DAvg("[PacerCallDuration_1]","tblCandidates","[CallDate] Between DateAdd('d', -" & DateRng & ", Date()) And Date()")
```

where *CallDate* is ... the call date.